# Is MARTA a good option to commute to/through downtown Atlanta?

Tags: public-transport, atlanta, georgia-usa

I went on a business day trip to Atlanta last week and noticed there was a [MARTA stop](http://www.itsmarta.com/) next to my hotel.  As someone who generally avoids Atlanta because of the traffic, would I have been better off taking the first exit with [a MARTA station](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton_E._Holmes_%28MARTA_station%29) as opposed to driving to a parking lot in downtown Atlanta?

My two primary goals would be to reduce travel time, and safely avoid traffic.

Comment: Actually, as I reread this question: Are you specifically interested in MARTA's efficacy for a park-and-ride situation? Because if so, my answer is somewhat unhelpful I suspect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Marta is **amazing**, *if it goes where you want to go*. The systems range is relatively limited, particularly to the various suburban regions in the NW, NE, SW, and SE. That said, the stop in the airport is extremely convenient, and will take you right into the heart of downtown. If you don't need to go anyplace other than that, it's absolutely the best option to avoid the dreaded Atlanta traffic.